# Cannot compare types 'ndarray(dtype=object)' and 'str'

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, numpy

У меня есть набор данных в csv и словарь созданный классификатором. Нужно на место ключей поставить значения ключа (вот [пример](https://sun9-37.userapi.com/c857616/v857616214/ae29c/BuR6RcnEqss.jpg) ). Сначала я пытался делать это через вот такой код

```
for key, value in xxx.items(): 
    lime_df.replace(value, key, inplace = True)
```

но замена затянулась на несколько дней. Сейчас я использую вот такой код:

```
lime_df.replace(mapping,inplace = True)
```

, но получаю ошибку:

> TypeError: Cannot compare types 'ndarray(dtype=object)' and 'str'

Вот так выглядит словарь:

```
{-5.486750964678322e-08: '2', 1.187718366754473e-17: '3', -7.059511863971579e-10: '10',
 -3.0349327687745536e+16: '18', -8.017016298890468e-18: '15', 107.15808868408203: '1',
 -8.300757059487296e-08: '5', -2.1828310439085026e+32: '13', -1.3752891451707128e+38: '8',
 5.882867218031023e-22: '14', -1.0941715971078361e+23: '17', -8.360684200807262e-18: '11',
 -1.0765597196911002e+36: '4', -1.5831559552949374e+38: '7', -1.5324417530020214e-27: '9', }
```

Все значения в таблице категориальные, поэтому для классификатора я использую

```
lime_df.astype(str)
```

И если вызвать `lime_df.dtypes`, он пишет, что все колонки имеют тип **object**.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Помогите исправить ошибку и решить задачу!

Comment: [Как наиболее эффективно задать вопрос, связанный с обработкой и/или анализом данных (например: по Pandas / Numpy / SciPy / SciKit Learn / SQL)?](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/7060/)

Comment: @MaxU Я не могу предоставить датасет :( Возможно ли предположить в чем проблема, без данных?

Comment: Воспроизводимый датасет - не значит оригинальный! Это тот, который позволяет __воспроизвести данную ошибку__.

Comment: `Возможно ли предположить в чем проблема, без данных?` - это как лечить пациента по телефону...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В чем именно была проблема узнать не удалось, но ошибка пропала при по строчной загрузке данных:

```
for i in range(0,df.shape[0]):

    df_train = df1.iloc[i, :]

    xxx = train_pool.get_cat_feature_hash_to_string() #создание словаря
    lol = dict(zip(xxx.values(), xxx.keys())) 

    cx = lime_df.replace(lol)

    for j in range(0, len(cx)):
        new.iat[i, j] = cx[j]
```